# POST list of objects in rails. How can I whitelist the list of objects in strong params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to post a list of objects called tasks that looks like the following.

```
{
  // Shared attributes
  "parent_id": "1",
  "author": "Name Name",
  // Task list
  "tasks": [
   {"name":"task 1"}, 
   {"name":"task 2"}...
  ]
}
```

In my controller, I have the following, which iterates through tasks, appends the shared attributes, and creates a new Task object:

```
task_params[:tasks].each do |task|
      new_params = task
      new_params[:parent_id] = task_params[:parent_id]
      new_params[:author] = task_params[:author]

      new_task = Task.new(new_params)
end
```

The problem is that :tasks isn't showing up in my task_params despite being passed in as a parameter. This seems to be because it isn't whitelisted in strong_params, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. It looks to me like I can only whitelist parameters that correspond to attr_accessors. So how can I pass in the custom parameter tasks through strong_params and into the controller method?

Edit:

My params definition:

```
def task_params
     params.require(:task).permit(:parent_id, :author, tasks: [:name])
end
```

Rails output:

```
  Parameters: {"parent_id"=>1, "author"=> "Name name", "tasks"=>[{"name"=>"task 1"}, {"name"=>"task 2"}], "task"=>{"job_id"=>1, "author"=>"Name name"}}
```

But when I print the task params in the controller:

```
{"parent_id"=>1, "author"=>"Name name"}
```

Comment: *"I can only whitelist parameters that correspond to attr_accessors"* <- Hm, this doesn't sound quite right. May we see your `params.require(...).permit(...)`? (Added to question, please, not in comments.)

Comment: params.require(:task).permit(:parent_id, :author, tasks: [:name])

As mentioned in below comment, also tried making tasks just a string and doing
params.require(:task).permit(:parent_id, :author, :tasks)

Still no dice. Still think it's because the model doesn't have an underlying tasks attribute.

Comment: I'm thinking it's because params.require(:task) is automatically filtering out anything not part of the :task model.

Comment: Could you also add to your question your full `params`? I believe your hunch about filtering items not part of the `:task` model isn't correct. But, it would help to see those `params`.

Comment: Updated the question with info

Comment: So, I didn't seem to have any problem with permitting `tasks` (see answer). So, I'm still thinking your hunch about what's going on isn't quite right.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [documentation on nested parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters) with Strong Parameters. You'd do something like:

```
params.permit(:parent_id, :author, tasks: [:name])
```

Comment: Doesn't help. I've even tried setting tasks to be a string ("tasks":"Hello world") and permitting it, but :tasks still doesn't seem to be passed through to task_params because it doesn't have an attribute accessor.

Comment: @JCDJulian if the given json structure is received in `params`, then defining a method named `task_params` comprising this solution should make the controller action work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are the tasks associated to one another in the model (might be worth copying that code into the question)? If so, do you just need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

Docs are here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

That way, by adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks` (or however you're naming the association) and using `fields_for` in the form, you should be able to access task data in the params (it'll still need permitting).

Put simply, from the docs:

> Defines an attributes writer for the specified association(s).

If you're using the stringified task data, you can probably use an `attr_reader` in the model to allow this to be passed in the params.

This help?

Answer (score 0):

Your params, as posted in your question, are malformed (missing a comma, a close bracket, etc.). That's probably a cut and paste error, I'm guessing. So, let's assume they are supposed to look like this:

```
{
  task: {
    "parent_id"=>1, 
    "author": "Name name", 
    "tasks"=>[
      {"name"=>"task 1"}, 
      {"name"=>"task 2", "task"=>{"job_id"=>1, "author"=>"Name name"}}
    ]
  }
}
```

Then if I do this in console:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(task: {"parent_id"=>1, "author": "Name name", "tasks"=>[{"name"=>"task 1"}, {"name"=>"task 2", "task"=>{"job_id"=>1, "author"=>"Name name"}}]})

task_params = params.require(:task).permit(:parent_id, :author, tasks: [:name, task: [:job_id, :author]])

task_params[:tasks].each do |task|
  puts task.merge!(parent_id: task_params[:parent_id], author: task_params[:author])
end
```

Then I see from the `puts` statements:

```
{"name"=>"task 1", "parent_id"=>1, "author"=>"Name name"}
{"name"=>"task 2", "task"=>{"job_id"=>1, "author"=>"Name name"}, "parent_id"=>1, "author"=>"Name name"}
```

Which would be your arguments for `Task.new`, which you could do as:

```
task_params[:tasks].each do |task|
  new_task = Task.new(task.merge!(parent_id: task_params[:parent_id], author: task_params[:author]))
end
```